# Does deleting files via the command prompt using the del keyword offer any built in recovery such as the recycle bin?

Tags: windows, command-line, data-recovery

So if a user did something like

```
cd super_important_directory
del /s /q *.*
```

in the command prompt, does Windows push those files to the recycle bin?  Are they permanently deleted and the only recovery option is specialized software?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: If this happened on your computer, turn it off immediately and use a different computer to recover the files. This gives you the best chance of recovering the files without any corruption. Even if you don't install any software, simple things like browsing the web will copy temp files onto your computer, and that very well could overwrite your data.

Comment: You would have to use data recovery software.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

No, there is no recovery for files deleted from the command line and it is a "permanent" delete.

### Not as Short Answer

The `del` command doesn't wipe the data portion of the file, it merely removes the entry from the filesystem.

This means that with specialized software, recovery *may* be possible, if nothing else has written over that area of the disk (as far as the system is aware, that area is now "free" space).

In contrast, the recycle bin is just a place where files get moved to, so the file system is still aware of their existence.

### What you can do:

The best way to prevent users from doing this is to prevent them from deleting the files.

Take a look at the permissions of a file:

1. Right click on the file.
2. Select **Properties**.
3. Click the **Security** tab.

The best way to do that, is to prevent them modifying them at all, by changing the permissions to and removing `Modify` and `Write`.

If users must be able to modify the files, then it is possible to use the more detailed permissions to prevent deletion but still allow modifications.

To get to the Advanced permissions, click **Advanced** in the security tab.

You can keep the rights granted with `Modify` and then just uncheck the `Delete` permission.

Make sure they also don't have the `Delete Subfolders and Files` permission on the parent folder, otherwise they will be able to delete the file anyway.

#### More Details

See [How to set, view, change, or remove special permissions for files and folders in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;308419) (it applies to any Windows version using NTFS).

Answer (score 0):

no I dont think this is the case. After i did `del foobar.txt`, I found no foobar.txt in my bin. Command line is considered a tool for ""professionals"". Also you do not want all the files you delete with a batch file to stick around until the user feels the need to eventually empty the bin. Often the user doesn't even know that some batch file has deleted something.

Under linux you can make an alias for the `rm` command and redirect it to some other command, or set other options. For example you can make it ask the "are you sure"-thing. But I do not know if there is such a thing like aliases on windows.

You also could restrict cmd access for your normal users. I don not believe that they can go and delete system files anyways.